# The Code Won't Execute all

Tags: c#, winforms, calculated-field

I have the following code:

```
private void G1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

            decimal quantity = 0, cost = 0;
            decimal   totalstock = 0, newtotalstock = 0;
            if (decimal.TryParse(G1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["RealExport"].Value.ToString(), out quantity) && decimal.TryParse(G1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Cost"].Value.ToString(), out cost))
            {
                decimal price = quantity * cost;
                G1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Total"].Value = price.ToString();
            }

            if (decimal.TryParse(G1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["TotalStock"].Value.ToString(), out totalstock) && decimal.TryParse(G1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["RealExport"].Value.ToString(), out quantity))
            {
                newtotalstock = totalstock - quantity;
                G1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["TotalStock"].Value = newtotalstock.ToString();
                return;
            }
            decimal avai = 0, newavai = 0;
            if (decimal.TryParse(G1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["RealExport"].Value.ToString(), out quantity) && decimal.TryParse(G1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["AvailableStock"].Value.ToString(), out avai))
            {
                newavai = avai - quantity;
                G1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["AvailableStock"].Value = newavai.ToString();
                return;
            } }
```

The problem is, it only **execute 2 out of 3** the code, I mean, when the **newtotalstock** is calculated, the code will end.

I try to change the **newavai** to up above, and the result is the same, it will calculate the **newavai** and pass the **newtotalstock**. I dont know why, all the code are correct. Please help

Comment: Maybe that's because of `return;` statement in the end of `if` block ?

Comment: Debugger is your friend.

Comment: @Filburt oh dear, when I bring the question in here, that means I already debugged over 10 times

Comment: I doubt so. You would have seen that the last statement is `return`.

Comment: I gave you upvote, it's a good question and some beginners can learn something from it :) Sadly, a lot of people on this forum can't understand it (

Comment: Debugging doesn't mean simply *running* your code, it means *stepping* through every single statement. Set a breakpoint at the very beginning of your method and hit F10 to find out what really happens. If you had done this, you could have come up with a more specific problem than *"The Code Won't Execute all"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

word "return" ends function, **if you are using void type method you don't really need to use return, unless you want to quit it at certain point**. The code after "return" will never be executed (only exception might be during usage "yield return", but that is another story).

```
void someMethod()
{
  doSomething();
  return;
  StartWorldWarThree(); //no waries, this will never be executed :)
}
```

Furethermore you can always make a breakpoint in your code (click on the left border of your window, or just read about it) and then check how your code is being executed :) F10/F11 to make step in your code, F5 to go to next breakpoint or end execution, if there are no more breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Taking in count that all conditions are true the return; will stop executing the rest of the code, if you want the 3 if to be executed, remove the return; and place it the last line of the method as

```
void Method() {
  if() {}
  if() {}
  if() {}
  return;
}
```

Or dont place it at all, because that method is void and does not need it

Comment: read the last sentence before commenting